# How can I make a heat map at given x and y points with the values for z?

Tags: python, heatmap

I am attempting to make a heat map for the angle of detection at given x and y values scanned from an instrument. I currently have a list of x points, y points, and the corresponding angle for that (x, y) pair.
[this is similar to how I want my data to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o94Ah.png)

My data currently looks like this:

```
x_points = [-0.135758, -0.133424, -0.133535, -0.133645, -0.133757...]

y_points = [0.131015, 0.127845, 0.127903, 0.127963, 0.128011...]

philist = [-17.101448168993848, -33.08916344731352, -1.8235472999129623, -12.288914556808527, 34.544133945256874...]
```

I have tried:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

zi = griddata((x_points, y_points), philist, (x_points, y_points))

CS = plt.contourf(x_points, y_points, zi, 15, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow)

plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

But I am getting an error on the grid data line that reads:

```
  File "/Users/forks/Desktop/ARP/Slope.py", line 76, in <module>
    zi = griddata((x_points, y_points), philist, (x_points, y_points),  method='cubic')

  File "/Users/forks/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/_ndgriddata.py", line 277, in griddata
    ip = CloughTocher2DInterpolator(points, values, fill_value=fill_value,

  File "interpnd.pyx", line 912, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.CloughTocher2DInterpolator.__init__

  File "interpnd.pyx", line 79, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.NDInterpolatorBase.__init__

  File "interpnd.pyx", line 193, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd._check_init_shape

ValueError: different number of values and points
```

I have also tried to do a 2D histogram, but the data does not fit well with that as I can't find a way to specify the z value to a specific (x, y) pair.

Lastly, I tried:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

z_min, z_max = -np.abs(philist).max(), np.abs(philist).max()
c = ax.pcolormesh(x_points, y_points, philist, vmin=z_min, vmax=z_max)

ax.axis([x_points.min(), x_points.max(), y_points.min(), y_points.max()])
fig.colorbar(c, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

This code returns an error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/forks/Desktop/ARP/Slope.py", line 76, in <module>
    c = ax.pcolormesh(x_points, y_points, philist, vmin=z_min, vmax=z_max)
  File "/Users/forks/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1442, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "/Users/forks/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 6220, in pcolormesh
    X, Y, C, shading = self._pcolorargs('pcolormesh', *args,
  File "/Users/forks/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5727, in _pcolorargs
    nrows, ncols = C.shape[:2]
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: 'I have tried different methods but haven't gotten any success' ---- Please add what you have tried and what error you are getting exactly.

Comment: @TheHungryCub I have made edits to be more specific about my issue and what I have tried, thank y'all!

Comment: The problem is that `C.shape[:2]` in the matplotlib code evaluates to a tuple with only one value, but this line of code expects a tuple with two values. This most likely means you are not calling `ax.pcolormesh()` correctly. You will need to determine what you are doing wrong there.

Comment: To track this down, I suggest looking at the matplotlib code to determine where the value of `C` comes from. To start, it looks like it is assigned by `X, Y, C, shading = self._pcolorargs(...)`. So what is `_pcolorargs()` and what does it return?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the code in the question is really just doing this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Given lists
x_points = [-0.135758, -0.133424, -0.133535, -0.133645, -0.133757]
y_points = [0.131015, 0.127845, 0.127903, 0.127963, 0.128011]
philist = [-17.101448168993848, -33.08916344731352, -1.8235472999129623, -12.288914556808527, 34.544133945256874]

# Create a scatter plot
plt.scatter(x_points, y_points, c=philist, cmap='viridis')

# Add a colorbar to show the scale of `philist`
plt.colorbar()

# Set labels for the axes
plt.xlabel('X points')
plt.ylabel('Y points')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

which gives this:

[image]

It seems that the question is attempting to smooth the points in the chart above. So something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# Given lists
x_points = np.array([-0.135758, -0.133424, -0.133535, -0.133645, -0.133757])
y_points = np.array([0.131015, 0.127845, 0.127903, 0.127963, 0.128011])
phi_values = np.array([-17.101448168993848, -33.08916344731352, -1.8235472999129623, -12.288914556808527, 34.544133945256874])

# Create a grid of points
xi, yi = np.linspace(x_points.min(), x_points.max(), 100), np.linspace(y_points.min(), y_points.max(), 100)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

# Interpolate the values of phi_values onto the grid
zi = griddata((x_points, y_points), phi_values, (xi, yi), method='cubic')

# Plot the heatmap using contourf
plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, levels=100, cmap='viridis')
plt.colorbar(label='Phi values')
plt.scatter(x_points, y_points, c='black', s=5)  # Optionally, plot the original points on top
plt.xlabel('X points')
plt.ylabel('Y points')
plt.title('Smoothed Heatmap')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

which gives this:

[image]

The second chart might look better with more data.